# C Compile Error Pointer

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors

Hey Guys I got a Compile Error in my C Project with a Function Pointer.

Thank you for your help :)

---

**Folder Structure:**

**Main Folder:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjhfo.png)

**Lib Folder:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OstPB.png)

**Heder Folder:**

*Path :* `C-Lib/Headers`

File(s) : `ShowPointer.h`

---

**Code (Main.c):**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "./Headers/ShowPointer.h"

int main(){
    printf("Hej this is written in VIM some C code.\n");
    getchar();

}
```

**Code (ShowPointer.c):**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "../Headers/ShowPointer.h"

void ExPointer(int *pPointer, int *pPointerMax){
    for (int i = *pPointer; i<*pPointerMax; i++){
        printf("%d. %d %p\n", i, *pPointerMax-i, pPointerMax);
    }
    getchar();
}
```

**Code (ShowPointer.h):**

```
#ifndef SHOWPOINTER_FILE
#define SHOWPOINTER_FILE

typedef void ExPointer (*)(int , int);

#endif
```

---

**Compile:**
I do Compile this Project whit this code:

```
gcc -o main main.c Lib/ShowAddress.c
```

**Error:**
Out come of the Compile error text (code):

```
In file included from main.c:2:0:
./Headers/ShowPointer.h:4:25: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
 typedef void ExPointer (*)(int , int);
                         ^
In file included from Lib/ShowAddress.c:2:0:
Lib/../Headers/ShowPointer.h:4:25: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
 typedef void ExPointer (*)(int , int);
```

---

**Sorry for me bad English.**

Comment: What is that `typedef` even supposed to do?

Comment: The header declares `ExPointer` to be the type of a pointer to a function that accepts two `int` arguments and returns `void`.   ShowPointer.cpp defines (not just declares) `ExPointer` to be an actual function that accepts two pointers to `int` as arguments, and returns `void.    There is no relationship whatsoever between the declaration in the header and the definition, but there needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
typedef void (*ExPointer)(int , int);
```

[How to create a typedef for function pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038430/how-to-create-a-typedef-for-function-pointers)

Comment: Now i get this problem : `Lib/ShowAddress.c:4:6: error: ‘ExPointer’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
 void ExPointer(int *pPointer, int *pPointerMax){
      ^
In file included from Lib/ShowAddress.c:2:0:
Lib/../Headers/ShowPointer.h:4:16: note: previous declaration of ‘ExPointer’ was here
 typedef void (*ExPointer)(int , int); 
`But Thanks for help

Comment: Perhaps it isn't clear then what you're trying to do. If ExPointer is an actual function, then you can't create a function pointer typedef with the same name. You might want to clarify by editing your original post.